# Permalink of custom post type partly broken

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, custom-post-type-archives

I'm running into some issues while working with a custom post type (CPT). The problem is that the permalinks of the CPT are fine for a single post but not for the archive/overview page.

The website that I'm working should have an archive page with all kind of clothes (CPT) categorized by brand.

The slug of the CPT should be website.com/cloths/brand-name/clothing-name. That's all working fine. Also the taxomomy overview pages like website.com/cloths/brand-name are fine. However the overview/archive page is broken and returns a 404 instead of website.com/cloths/

I really don't know why this is happening especially when the taxonomy and single post permalinks are all fine. I've already changed the permalink settings but without any result. If I create a custom page template with the code that I'm using on the archive template the permalink is fine for the verview/archive page but the pagination is broken, the 2nd page returns a 404.

This is the code that I'm using to create the CPT and desired permalink structure:

```
function my_custom_post_product() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Collectie', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Kleding stuk', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Nieuw kleding stuk', 'reis' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Nieuw kleding stuk toevoegen' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Kleding stuk wijzigen' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'Nieuw item' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'Alle kleding stukken' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'Bekijk item' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Doorzoek collectie' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'Geen kleding stuk gevonden  ' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Geen kleding stuk gevonden in de prullenbak' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Collectie'
);
$args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Nieuw kleding stuk toevoegen',
    'public'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    'has_archive'   => true,
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'rewrite'       => array('slug' => 'kleding/%merk%','with_front' => false),
    'query_var'     => true,
);
register_post_type( 'kleding', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_product' );

/* Cloths custom taxonomy */
function my_taxonomies_product() {
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Merken', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Merk', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Product Categories' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'Alle merken' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Product Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Product Category:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Product Category' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Product Category' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Nieuw merk toevoegen' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Product Category' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Merk' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'public'        => true,
    'query_var'     => 'merk',
    'rewrite'       =>  array('slug' => 'kleding' ),
    '_builtin'      => false,
);
register_taxonomy( 'merk', 'kleding', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_product', 0 );

/* Permalink filter Collectie */
add_filter('post_link', 'brand_permalink', 1, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'brand_permalink', 1, 3);

function brand_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
if (strpos($permalink, '%merk%') === FALSE) return $permalink;
    // Get post
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if (!$post) return $permalink;

    // Get taxonomy terms
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'merk');
    if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0]))
        $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    else $taxonomy_slug = 'geen-merk';

return str_replace('%merk%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

Please note that some parts of the code above are in Dutch. 'merk' = 'brand-name' and 'kleding' = 'cloths'

Comment: have you tried setting `has_archive` to the desired slug rather than just `true`?

Comment: Thanks so much! Changing is to the slug resolved the 404 and now it's also using the correct archive template.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you haven't connected your custom post type and taxonomy completely. I'm not sure if this is causing your current issue, but it would be the first thing I would try.

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type):

> When registering a post type, always register your taxonomies using
>   the taxonomies argument. If you do not, the taxonomies and post type
>   will not be recognized as connected when using filters such as
>   parse_query or pre_get_posts. This can lead to unexpected results and
>   failures.

So, I would add to your post-type args:

```
'taxonomies' => array('merk'),
```

and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: I've added it but it didn't fixes the problem. But the suggestion about the archive slug posted above solved the problem.